# MinionPro, including math, in ConTeXt

Tags: math-mode, fonts, context

A rather simple question, which probably will have a complex answer. I'm trying to migrate to ConTeXt, since I want to have a layout not easily achieved with LaTeX (grid...). In LaTeX, MinionPro is working fine, including the math, after some voodoo and lots of hair pulling. I haven't touched it since. Now, how to get this stuff to work in ConTeXt as well? I started with the body font, that's the easy part. I have no clue where to look for the math font, or how to port/translate the TeX stuff I have to something ConTeXt will understand. Where do I begin?

Edit: To clarify, what I currently have is

```
\starttypescript [serif] [minionpro]
    \definefontsynonym [Serif] [name:minionproregular] [features=default]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [minionpro]
    \definetypeface [minionpro] [rm] [serif] [minionpro] [default]
    \definetypeface [minionpro] [mm] [math] [minionpro] [default]
\stoptypescript

\usetypescript [minionpro]
\setupbodyfont [minionpro,10pt]

\starttext
Hi, this is text. A formula: $x + y = z$.
\stoptext
```

This is obviously not enough information to make it go, it helpfully cries out with the error

```
error on line 14 in file tmp.tex: Math error: parameter \Umathquad\displaystyle is not set ...
```

Comment: `\setupfontfamily[math][Some Math Font]` should be sufficient to change the math font. Or define your own family if you don't want to change the default: `\definefontfamily[myfamily][math][Some Math Font]` and then `\setupbodyfont[myfamily]`.

Comment: Is there an opentype math font that matches minonpro? If not, then you have to create a virtual math font.

Comment: As far as I know there isn't. For LaTeX there's a package which sets things up to work. Is there documentation somewhere about how to create such a virtual math font? Or a readable example?

Comment: @Michel: Read Section 4 of http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-2/tb95mahajan-cmath.pdf. But that article is more than 4 years old. The current organization of files is a bit different, so you will have to grep around a bit to find the exact files. For an example, see `$TEXMF/tex/context/fonts/tx-math.lfg` and `$TEXMF/tex/context/base/type-imp-texgyre.mkiv` (grep for `txmath`).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I'll see if I can create a solution, and if so I'll post it here. Hopefully people will be able to use it, too, or to help improve it.

Comment: Right, as I understand it, the virtual thing is used to build OpenType math fonts using TeX fonts. Situation is: Minion Pro comes as OpenType font, and is converted to a TeX font. Most elegant would be to use the OpenType stuff in ConTeXt. Can the virtual math font mechanism be used to build a font out of an OpenType non-math font? And is there some example of this? Because, as I understand it, maps like tex-it, tex-ma, tex-mb are meant for dealing with TeX fonts, right?

Comment: Short update, sorry for the comment spam, but the mapping stuff works just as well for mapping from OpenType to OpenType Math. It only needs a lot of mapping work :P So far, italic letters and italic Greek is working.

Comment: You can map MnSymbol (http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/fonts/mnsymbol/otf/) too if you miss something in the basic Minion OTF files. Do you know Minion Math?(http://www.typoma.com/en/fonts.html)

Comment: Yes, I'm in the process of mapping MnSymbol stuff now. It is complicated, because MnSymbol has virtual sizes it seems, haven't got that to work properly yet. And I saw Minion Math, yes, but I would like to get the existing setup to work with ConTeXt :) It's a good learning exercise, haha...

Answer (score 9):

To use the Minion fonts in ConTeXt:

1. Make sure that you have the fonts. Running

   ```
   mtxrun --script fonts --list --pattern="*minion*" --all
   ```

   should give you:

   ```
   minionpro             minionprobold      MinionPro-Bold.otf
   minionprobold         minionprobold      MinionPro-Bold.otf
   minionproboldit       minionproboldit    MinionPro-BoldIt.otf
   minionprobolditalic   minionproboldit    MinionPro-BoldIt.otf
   minionproit           minionproit        MinionPro-It.otf
   minionproitalic       minionproit        MinionPro-It.otf
   minionpronormal       minionproit        MinionPro-It.otf
   minionproregular      minionproregular   MinionPro-Regular.otf
   ```
2. The Minion fonts do not come with a accompanying math fonts. However, for simple math you can use symbols from a different math font (e.g., Pagella Math), and use letters and digits from Minion. To do so, you need a recent (2013.12.20 or newer) version of ConTeXt. Then use the following test file:

   ```
   \definefontfamily [mainface] [rm] [Minion Pro]

   \definefallbackfamily [mainface] [math] [Minion Pro] [math:lowercaseitalic] [force=yes]
   \definefallbackfamily [mainface] [math] [Minion Pro] [math:digitsnormal]    [force=yes]
   \definefontfamily     [mainface] [math] [TeX Gyre Pagella Math]

   \setupbodyfont[mainface]

   \starttext
   \input ward

   \startformula
     c^2 = a^2 + b^2
   \stopformula

   \stoptext
   ```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for italics in latest beta ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm93i.png)).

Comment: @HenriMenke: Hmm... I tried different combinations of `range` and `offset`, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Yes, something must have changed in a recent beta.  If you take a peek in the log, you'll notice that it tries to look up a, b, and c in the lowercase math italic slots (which are of course empty) rather than in the lowercase Latin slots.