# mathspec or mathastext equivalents for ConTeXt

Tags: math-mode, context, opentype

I have just started out with ConTeXt, and am wondering if there is a way to use fonts that do not have an OpenType math table or a specifically designed math font in the way that `mathspec` or `mathastext` work, but for ConTeXt.

I have tried [this approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150566/minionpro-including-math-in-context), but have not had any luck.

P.S: my MWE is the answer linked above.

**Edit:** Just to clarify, `mathspec` and `mathastext` allow you to typeset math without a specifically-made math font/a font with an OpenType math table.

Comment: Can you elaborate what 'in a way that mathspec or mathastext work' for those who are not familiar with the latex unicode-math package